# How to create custom maps in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create around 10 custom maps in swift. When I say maps, I mean tracks where players can navigate around. I'm not sure if it is better to do this in Sprite Kit or Unity.

An example is like this image:

[image]

This is just a snapshot form the game 'Coron'.

If someone has an answer to how I can create a custom map with custom shapes as the walls, will I be able to add physics body features to the walls and be able to chose programmatically which map is shown to the player?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you are thinking about using Sprite-Kit!

To answer your question, I will describe to you what I would do if I wanted to create a map such as the one you posted above. You can then decide for yourself if this framework is right for you.

1. To draw the map I would open up an image editor (I like GIMP). I would take out my handy little wacom pen if I needed it and I would draw exactly what you see.
2. since Sprite-Kit uses sprites I'd save two image files. In one, I would make the top and the middle space alpha/transparent and in other I'd do the opposite and make the bottom and middle space transparent. Since Sprite-Kit uses distinct sprites I would make the bottom and top zig-zags separate entities and have the middle space be background colored.
3. Next, I'd export out of GIMP and into Xcode .png files. I would initialize two `SKSpriteNode`s with images from the bottom and top zig-zag and would position them so that they look similarly to how they are in the picture.
4. Finally, I'd add `SKPhysicsBody`s to both sprite nodes and quickly implement bit masks to test for contact and collision.

Extra: If the map is big and parts come off the screen, its easy to place everything into a container which you can move so the user can see the different parts. With Xcode 7, there is also a `SKCameraNode` feature which allows you to just move around without any of the container junk!

If there was a need to have several maps/levels then I would simply separate them into several `SKScene`s and just use the view to transition between them when I needed to. I know Unity has some pretty sweet features and their 3d support is pretty much unrivaled but I'd say Sprite-Kit is pretty straightforward and quick if you wanted a smooth, quality 2d game.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I've read your answer, I realise how much easier it is than I first thought. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Glad you think so too :))))

Comment: Just one more thing, not a whole question, but a short one. Which size should I create the document to make the maps if I want it to be available on all device sizes?

Comment: The image files? It doesn't really matter, thats up to you to make them to high or low quality. You do have the option though to use different resolutions on different devices which means you would create one lower resolution and then for something like the iPad would create an image twice the size/resolution and put @2x at the end to specify Xcode to use it only for high resolution displays. However, thats totally optional and isn't an issue until you are about to release the app.

Comment: Heres a link to a tutorial on the subject if you are really worried :D http://www.raywenderlich.com/49695/sprite-kit-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-1

Comment: Also, if I wanted a ball to travel around the track (like in the image in my question), would it be easier just to make the sprites (the two wall sprites) bigger than the screen, and then when I tilt the device (to move the ball) I just move the sprites and keep the ball in the middle of the screen?

Comment: Yeah that would be definitely be possible. Did you see what I wrote in the Extra: section in my answer? I think you'd definitely be interested in the camera node feature for that.

Comment: Yes, but I don't really understand the part about placing them in a container?

Comment: Its mostly just semantics that will become clear later, but basically in the earlier versions of the Sprite Kit  to move everything you had to add all sprites into like a worldNode container and then move that around. It's really nothing special or complicated, Im just getting into more of the details.